# Loading usercontrol once task is completed

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross

I have a windows phone 8.1 app, and when I move from a list to details page.  I load a hub page and retrieve the items necessary through an async task. however this process takes a fairly long time as is retrieving a lot of data. as such my bindings is throwing an exception, is there a  way of telling the view to not load the user controls until the binding of isbusy is set to false? I'm using mvvmcross.

EDIT:

I was trying to avoid having to create temp data as the object is quite large , this is the reason i was getting the exceptions even though bindings should continue

```
 public string AccountTitle
    {
        get
        {
             return _fullAccount.CustomName;
        }

    }
```

cause the _full account was null, hence i wanted to stop binding (ie loading the usercontrol at all) from happening at all until the process was finished as their is nothing on the UI that can happen until it is completed
eventually i had to do the following

```
  public string AccountTitle
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsBusy) return "";
            else return _fullAccount.CustomName;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are binding to a property. Then I would give it some temporary data, and after the async task is done, rebind the data to the real data.

```
private BindType bindProp = TempData;
public BindType BindProp 
{
    get
    {
         return bindProp;
    }
}

private void LoadDone(BindType realData)
{
    bindProp= realData;
    // Notify BindProp property changed
}
```

But it is weird, usually if it is a `null` it should just continue, not give exceptions (but you didn't specify in the question more detail so I cannot help you more than this).

Also I would check the xaml to make sure that the bindings are correct, I feel there is something wrong there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , yeah i eventually had to do that ... i was trying to avoid having to create temp data as the object is quite large , this is the reason i was getting the exceptions even though bindings should continue

     public string AccountTitle
        {
            get
            {
                 return _fullAccount.CustomName;
            }

        }

cause the _full account was null, hence i wanted to stop binding from happening at all until the process was finished as their is nothing on the UI that can happen until it is completed

Comment: eventually i had to do the following 

      public string AccountTitle
        {
            get
            {
                if (IsBusy) return "";
                else return _fullAccount.CustomName;
            }

        }

Comment: @Barry have a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994637.aspx